# Event click while unchecking a checkbox in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms, checkbox

I have a checkbox where when enabled shows a div tag which shows "hyyj". What I need is that when I disable it we should be able to hide the div tag. I am posting the stackblitz link down here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vhxjkt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using several ways.

1. You can pass `$event` object along with `checkBtn` event. Keep value in a sync with model.

   ```
   (click)="checkBtn($event)"

   checkBtn({target: {checked }}) {
       this.ischeck = checked;
   }
   ```

   [**Forked Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1bdvn3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)
2. Either use template or model driven form.

   ```
   <input [(ngModel)]="isChecked" #checkbox 
     type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1">
   ```

   [**Forked Stackblitz** (template driven)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qjwfhn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oswf2h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html    Here I have brought all checkbox values into a table using for loop. When I enable one checkbox (the message appears) but when I enable another checkbox the message disappears. What I need is that that until all the checkbox gets disabled the message should be there and evenwhen two are more checkboxes are there the message should be there.

Comment: Open a new question, that will be better. Thanks

Comment: I have opened a new question. Please check that

Answer (score 0):

Change the implementation of `checkBtn` to be this:

```
checkBtn() {
    this.ischeck = !this.ischeck;
  }
```

This time it will assign it to be the opposite of its current value and it should work as you requested.

Or if you want to write a bit more code:

```
checkBtn() {
  if (this.isCheck === true) { // can also just be if (this.isCheck)
    this.isCheck = false;
  } else {
    this.isCheck = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oswf2h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html         Here I have brought all checkbox values into a table using for loop. When I enable one checkbox (the message appears) but when I enable another checkbox the message disappears. What I need is that that until all the checkbox gets disabled the message should be there and evenwhen two are more checkboxes are there the message should be there.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [(ngModel)] ?

You can set it like this.

```
<td> <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" [(ngModel)]="ischeck" name="vehicle1" value="Bike"></td>
```

Here every time the value of checks change you'll get the result into ischeck variable.

I Hope it could help you.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oswf2h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html    Here I have brought all checkbox values into a table using for loop. When I enable one checkbox (the message appears) but when I enable another checkbox the message disappears. What I need is that that until all the checkbox gets disabled the message should be there and evenwhen two are more checkboxes are there the message should be there.